# is image_downsize supposed to work inside a custom walker?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails, menuitem

I implemented this custom walker I based on the code here [Displaying a wordpress menu with submenu and thumbnail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25528602/displaying-a-wordpress-menu-with-submenu-and-thumbnail)

(it should retrieve the image URL to use it as css background, instead of rendering an actual img tag)

Everything works fine, except wp_get_attachment_image_src always returnes false.

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'generate_nav_images', 20, 4);

    add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'generate_nav_images', 20, 4);
    function generate_nav_images($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){

            if(has_post_thumbnail($item->object_id)){


                $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( (int)$item->object_id, 'thumbnail', false );

                $dom = new DOMDocument();
                $dom->loadHTML($item_output); 
                $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute( 'style' , 'background-image: url('. $thumb_url[0] . ');' );
                $item_output = $dom->saveHTML();
        }
        return $item_output;
    }
```

The pages DO have a thumbnail, the pages ID are returned ok, get_the_post_thumbnail() returns fine, but wp_get_attachment_image_src() doesn't.

I tracked the issue to many functions about image sizes returning false, except has_thumbnail().

The deeper "false" value I tracked was the filter "image_downsize" but then the function becomes too advanced for me :(

Is image_downsize even supposed to work inside a walker?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you solution:

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'generate_nav_images', 20, 4);
function generate_nav_images($item_output, $item, $depth, $args){
    if( $args->theme_location == "topnav") {
        if(has_post_thumbnail($item->object_id)){

            // get attachment ID
            $thumb_id = get_post_meta($item->object_id, '_thumbnail_id', true);
            $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumb_id, 'thumbnail', false );

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($item_output); 
            $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->setAttribute( 'style' , 'background-image: url('. $thumb_url[0] . ');' );
            $item_output = $dom->saveHTML();
        }
    }
    return $item_output;
}
```

wp_get_attachment_image_src() expect attachemnt id not Post Id.